# Closing a docx file if it's open

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm working with **docx files** and to prevent the `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` error, I tried to add `os.close()` in my code  but as I saw, it doesn't accept the file path, it accepts file descriptor as a parameter.So I tried that:

```
file_path = 'my file path'
mydoc = docx.Document()
mydoc.add_paragraph('text')
try:
    mydoc.save(file_path)
    return
except PermissionError:
    fd = os.open(file_path, os.O_WRONLY)
    os.close(fd)
    mydoc.save(file_path)
    return
```

But when I run it, it passes the first `PermissionError` error because of the error handling, but when it tries to do `fd = os.open(file_path, os.O_WRONLY)`, I got the same error. So is there a possible way to close a **docx file** if it's open?

**Edit:**

Here is the entire traceback

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\17326\PycharmProjects\newEksi\main2.py", line 194, in arat
    mydoc.save(dosya_yolu)
  File "C:\Users\17326\PycharmProjects\newEksi\venv\lib\site-packages\docx\document.py", line 167, in save
    self._part.save(path_or_stream)
  File "C:\Users\17326\PycharmProjects\newEksi\venv\lib\site-packages\docx\parts\document.py", line 111, in save
    self.package.save(path_or_stream)
  File "C:\Users\17326\PycharmProjects\newEksi\venv\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 172, in save
    PackageWriter.write(pkg_file, self.rels, self.parts)
  File "C:\Users\17326\PycharmProjects\newEksi\venv\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\pkgwriter.py", line 32, in write
    phys_writer = PhysPkgWriter(pkg_file)
  File "C:\Users\17326\PycharmProjects\newEksi\venv\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._zipf = ZipFile(pkg_file, 'w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Users\17326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/17326/Desktop/entries.docx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\17326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\17326\PycharmProjects\newEksi\main2.py", line 197, in arat
    fd = os.open(dosya_yolu, os.O_WRONLY)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/17326/Desktop/entries.docx'
```

Comment: What makes you think that the file is "open"?  Do you know that some other process has it open?  If you do, then you can't generally close a file that has been opened by another process.  You certainly can't do it the way you're trying to do it. - my guess is that you are not getting the `PermissionError` error because the file is open, but for some other reason, like you don't have permissions on the file or the target directory to write the file.

Comment: I'm trying to close it if it's open in the computer system, for example if user opened the word document while code is running, I want to close the file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have permission to this file-target directory, because when the file is close, my code works fine.

Comment: Can you add your entire traceback? It looks like you get an permission error while saving the file, while handling that error you attempt to reopen the same file, causing another permission error.

Comment: i agree with @Steve, do you know for sure you aren't getting the permission error because you're not having the sufficient permission to write to the file? Did you try running the script as admin from your terminal?

Comment: Just like I said, it works very well when the word document is not open. I edited the question with the entire traceback.

Comment: You're trying to force-close a file that's in use by another application? While this may technically be doable through evil WinAPI hacks, I'd strongly recommend against it as you have no way of knowing what state the file is in and you could very well clobber its contents. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "open" file in `python-docx`. When you read in a file to edit it with `document = Document("my-file.docx")`, `python-docx` reads in the file and that's it. Yes, it is open for a split second while it's being read in, but it does not remain open. The open/close cycle ends before the `Document()` call returns.

Same when you're saving the file. When you call `document.save("my-output-file.docx")`, the file is opened, written, and closed, all before the `.save()` method returns.

So it's not like Word itself where you open a file, work on it for a while and then save and close it. You're just reading a "starting" file into memory, making changes to that in-memory object, and then later writing the in-memory representation (almost always to a different file).

The comments are on the right track. Look for a permission problem not allowing you to write a file in that location that is not connected to an open file, unless you have the file in question open in Word or something at the time your program runs.

Answer (score 2):

python-docx can open a document from a so-called file-like object. It can also save to a file-like object. This can be handy when you want to get the source or target document over a network connection or from a database and don’t want to (or aren’t allowed to) interact with the file system. In practice this means you can pass an open file or StringIO/BytesIO stream object to open or save a document like so:

```
f = open('foobar.docx', 'rb')
document = Document(f)
f.close()

# or

with open('foobar.docx', 'rb') as f:
    source_stream = StringIO(f.read())
document = Document(source_stream)
source_stream.close()
...
target_stream = StringIO()
document.save(target_stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to add to others' explanation, by showing some code.

```
file_path = 'my file path'
mydoc = docx.Document()
mydoc.add_paragraph('text')
hasError = False
try:
    fd = open(file_path)
    fd.close()
    mydoc.save(file_path)
except PermissionError:
    raise Exception("oh no some other process is using the file or you don't have access to the file, try again when the other process has closed the file")
    hasError = True
finally:
    if not hasError:
        mydoc.save(file_path)
return
```

Answer (score 0):

**Closing doc/docx file if its open using Python**                                              1. Save the doc/docx file                                                                           2. Close the doc/docx file                                                                          3. Quit the Word Application

```
from win32com import client as wc
w = wc.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = w.Documents.Open(file_path)
doc.SaveAs("Savefilename_docx.docx", 16)
doc.Close()
w.Quit()
```